# WPF C# MVVM Radio Button load list content

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hi guys i want to make a radio button how get args from list. I don't understand how can i create the list to implement all args in a radio button + textbox, something like this:

> Question1: What is cat?
> Answer 1: Animal
> Answer 2: Human
> Answer 3: Stone

how can i make bind if i have something like this:

```
<ListBox
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Height="313"
    Margin="57,29,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Width="681"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="This is question 1!" Margin="25" FontSize="25" />
                <RadioButton GroupName="First Question" IsChecked="False" Margin="10" Content="{Binding LoadRadioContent}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: If you're binding, the data should already be available, so you wouldn't be using a LoadRadioContent method, but the path to a property of the list item viewmodel. So as is, we don't have enough information; what does your view model look like?

Comment: @Kilazur https://pastebin.com/tddNp3Tm

Comment: @ClaudiuAndries try adding `Set { _LoadRadioContent = value; RaisePropertyChange(); }` in the setter of `LoadRadioContent` . To get RaisePropertyChange(), please implement the INotifyPropertyChanged's methods.

Comment: Can you please show your data class that you display in the `ListBox` and the initialization of the `ListBox`?

Comment: The data item should contain a property that holds the question, a collection of possible answers and a property that holds the correct answer. Then in your `DataTemplate` add another nested `ItemsControl` to replace the current `RadioButton` where `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` binds to the collection of possible answers. Then define a `DataTemplate` for the new `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`. This `DataTemplate` contains a `RadioButton` where `RadioButton.Content` binds to the current `DataContext` (the possible answer).

Comment: You now have a list of questions, where each question has a list of answers (radio buttons).

Comment: @BionicCode i have xaml file:https://pastebin.com/Y2htZD2b

Comment: And this C# code: https://pastebin.com/yeVVqbWN , don't work, my window it's force to close

Comment: I will try with observable collection but same thing...

Answer (score 1):

You must create a structure of a list of questions, where each question has a list of possible answers.

The following example uses the `RelayCommand` implementation provided by [Microsoft Docs: Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic).
It uses a composed data model consisting of `Question` and `Answer`:

**Question.cs**

```
public class Question : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public Question(string summary, Answer answer)
  {
    this.Summary = summary;
    this.Answer = answer;
  }

  public string Summary { get; set; }
  public Answer Answer { get; set; }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**Answer.cs**

```
public class Answer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public Answer(IEnumerable<IChoice> choices)
  {
    this.Choices = choices;
  }

  // Evaluates the answer(s)
  public bool Validate()
  {
    this.IsCorrect = this.Choices.All(
      choice => choice.IsValidChoice && choice.IsSelected 
                || !choice.IsValidChoice && !choice.IsSelected);
    return this.IsCorrect;
  }

  public ICommand CheckAnswerCommand =>
    new RelayCommand(answer => Validate());
  
  public IEnumerable<IChoice> Choices { get; set; }

  private bool isCorrect;
  public bool IsCorrect
  {
    get => this.isCorrect;
    private set
    {
      this.isCorrect = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**IChoice**

```
public interface IChoice : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // Marks whether the choice is a valid answer
  bool IsValidChoice { get; }

  // Selects the choice as an answer
  bool IsSelected { get; set; }

  string Text { get; set; }
}
```

**MultiChoice.cs**

```
class MultiChoice : IChoice
{
  public MultiChoice(string text, bool isValidChoice)
  {
    this.Text = text;
    this.IsValidChoice = isValidChoice;
  }

  #region Implementation of IChoice

  public bool IsValidChoice { get; }

  private bool isSelected;    
  public bool IsSelected
  {
    get => this.isSelected;
    set
    {
      this.isSelected = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private string text;    
  public string Text
  {
    get => this.text;
    set
    {
      this.text = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  #endregion

  #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  #endregion
}
```

**SingleChoice.cs**

```
class SingleChoice : IChoice
{
  public SingleChoice(string text, bool isValidChoice)
  {
    this.Text = text;
    this.IsValidChoice = isValidChoice;
  }

  #region Implementation of IChoice

  public bool IsValidChoice { get; }    
  
  private bool isSelected;    
  public bool IsSelected
  {
    get => this.isSelected;
    set
    {
      this.isSelected = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private string text;    
  public string Text
  {
    get => this.text;
    set
    {
      this.text = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  #endregion

  #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged    

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;    
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  #endregion
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }

  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.Questions = new ObservableCollection<Question>
    {
      new Question(
        "Which number follows '1'?",
        new Answer(
          new[]
          {
            new SingleChoice("3", false), 
            new SingleChoice("15", false), 
            new SingleChoice("2", true),
            new SingleChoice("7", false)
          })),
      new Question(
        "Which creature can fly?",
        new Answer(
          new[]
          {
            new MultiChoice("Bird", true),
            new MultiChoice("Elephant", false),
            new MultiChoice("Bee", true),
            new MultiChoice("Cat", false)
          }))
    };
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <CheckBox Content="Answer 1 is Correct?" IsChecked="{Binding Questions[0].Answer.IsCorrect, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <CheckBox Content="Answer 2 is Correct?" IsChecked="{Binding Questions[1].Answer.IsCorrect, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:Question}">
          <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Summary}" />
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Answer.Choices}">
              <ListBox.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:SingleChoice}">
                  <RadioButton Content="{Binding Text}" 
                               GroupName="Answer"
                               IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                               Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=DataContext.Answer.CheckAnswerCommand}" />
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:MultiChoice}">
                  <CheckBox Content="{Binding Text}" 
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=DataContext.Answer.CheckAnswerCommand}" />
                </DataTemplate>
              </ListBox.Resources>
            </ListBox>
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Ok it's a good ideea, but i don;t really understand all your code. I want to keep my code simple. What i want to make: a simple quiz (next/prev) with differite answer. You show me a method, it's great, but i want to make simple. I use Prism framework, and my code is this: css: https://pastebin.com/UCtBgFPV xaml: https://pastebin.com/veLbp7Gr, if you see, i want to have question with multiple answer(checkbox), and question with simple answer(radio button). if i have simple question i make visible first listbox, if not i make visible second listbox. I need a method to put multiple answer.

Comment: I create a IEnumerable of LoadRadioContentT but don't work, if i make simple string work. but i want to add more radioButton for one question and to keep right answer in my container. Give me a method...

Comment: Did you mean _"Give me a method, **please**"_? This "please" makes a subtle little difference, I think. What is next prev doing? I thought you show a bunch of questions in a `ListBox`. The code I have posted is very simple. I have updated it to support single answers and multi answers. This will work with Prism too. You may want to replace `RelayCommand` with Prism's `DelegateCommand`. What don't you understand? Please take your time to copy the short example an run it. It's a working example which will help you to understand the details. You can copy all classes to a single file for testing.

Comment: Ok thangk you very much